# How to get the custom fields from a custom object

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, lookup

I have an object `Event_Booking__c`. I want to get all the fields from that object which is related to the `Event__c` object through `Event_ID__c` lookup.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: u can refer this previous discussion on how to select all fields from an object : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49711/howto-wildcard-select-to-query-all-fields-of-objects-in-apex

Comment: @VamsiKrishna what I mean sir is get all the fields.. Not the Select * function or get data from fields selected..

Comment: u mean something like this ? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60710/how-to-get-all-fields-from-any-object-and-its-parent-object-in-apex?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dynamic Apex to perform describe call on object for which you want to get meta-data as described in below example:

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>();
fields.addAll((Event__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
```

Above code will return all fields of `Event__c` Object which will get stored in List of type String.